# API limits and how many concurrent API requests Salesforce can process

Tags: apex, rest-api, governorlimits

Just wondering if there is any limit to concurrent API requests into Salesforce.

We are beginning to expose Apex REST endpoints for external systems to call. We know we have a 24 hour API limit, where within 24 hours you only can process xyz number of API calls.

However what about concurrent call limit? In other words, how many API calls can Salesforce process at once? If 1,000,000 calls come inbound at the same time, we know that will reduce our 24 hour limit by 1,000,000. But will Salesforce struggle to process and return these calls? Will exceptions be thrown because the system is overloaded?

I know already there is a concurrent request limit for Apex for long-running transactions. If ~10+ Apex transactions occurring at the same time each take over 20 seconds, the system will lockup and throw concurrent request limit exceeded error. However this is different from how many concurrent API requests the system can process.

I have to imagine if there was such a limit, Salesforce would disclose it as it's vital to integrations to know how much output (or input) Salesforce can handle. But I'm not seeing any limit listed anywhere.

tl;dr - If we expose an Apex REST endpoint which only takes < 1 second to process, what happens if this endpoint is called 1,000,000 times at the same exact time? Will the system respond or lock up/error out?

Answer (score 1):

There is no *specific* limit on concurrent requests, but that doesn't mean you can just throw arbitrarily large amounts of traffic at your Salesforce org and expect it to be fine and dandy.

One million *simultaneous* hits is... a lot of hits. I imagine that that's just a large number you grabbed rather than a realistic projection of your expected use.

You should realistically project your needed volume before you evaluate whether Salesforce is the right service to host this API or whether you need other infrastructure in addition to or instead of Salesforce, like a cache server or reverse proxy.

You can run your own performance and load testing against a sandbox if you want to, but you [need to notify Salesforce first](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335652&type=1) if you're testing with more than 50 users.